# How to add meta reducers to ngrx store in a standalone application?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

During Angular (v15) bootstrap, how should meta reducers be added to a standalone app?

Say I start with:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    ...
    provideStore(reducers, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true,
        strictStateSerializability: true,
        strictActionSerializability: true,
        strictActionWithinNgZone: true,
        strictActionTypeUniqueness: true
      }
    }),
    ...
  ]
}).catch(error => console.log('Bootstrap error', error));
```

The `provideStore` function doesn't seem to accept a metaReducers parameter (unless I'm missing something). I tried adding metaReducers using the module approach via `importProvidersFrom` (see below), but the meta reducers never run:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    ...
    importProvidersFrom(StoreModule.forRoot(undefined, { metaReducers })),
    provideStore(reducers, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true,
        strictStateSerializability: true,
        strictActionSerializability: true,
        strictActionWithinNgZone: true,
        strictActionTypeUniqueness: true
      }
    }),
    ...
  ]
}).catch(error => console.log('Bootstrap error', error));
```

I'm not finding anything in the NGRX (v15-v17) docs, nor via google / stack overflow search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [options docs](https://ngrx.io/api/store/RootStoreConfig) the [`provideStore`](https://ngrx.io/api/store/provideStore) function does support adding `metaReducers` next to the`runtimeChecks` attribute:

```
provideStore(reducers, {
  runtimeChecks: {},
  metaReducers: , // <--- Meta reducers here
})
```

Comment: Silly me, totally missed that it's an options property...